# Obtaining numerical value from Recurrence Table

Tags: list-manipulation, recursion, numerical-value

I'm trying to analyze the following sequence of numbers:

$$a_1 = 2 \quad \text{ s.t } \quad a_n = 4\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i
$$
I wrote the following code for creating a
Recurrence Table for this sequence of numbers:

```
rt = RecurrenceTable[{a[n + 1] == 4 Sum[a[n], {1, n}], a[1] == 2}, a, {n, 1, 10}]
```

But, I'm facing the following issue, when I try to evaluate the actual numerical value, I'm getting the following format as output:

$rt[[2]] = 4 \times \sum_{1}^{1}2$

Even when I run

```
N[rt[[2]]
```

The output is

```
4. NSum[2, {1, 1}]
```

The ouput for the FullForm is:

```
\!\(
TagBox[
StyleBox[
RowBox[{"Times", "[", 
RowBox[{"4", ",", 
RowBox[{"Sum", "[", 
RowBox[{"2", ",", 
RowBox[{"List", "[", 
RowBox[{"1", ",", "1"}], "]"}]}], "]"}]}], "]"}],
ShowSpecialCharacters->False,
ShowStringCharacters->True,
NumberMarks->True],
FullForm]\)
```

Any tips on how to get the numerical values? Is the error in the actual function for the definition of the Recurrence Table?

Comment: Já tentou usar LaTex?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
a[1] = 2;
a[n_] := a[n] = 4 Sum[a[i], {i, n - 1}]

Table[a[n], {n, 1, 10}]
```

> {2, 8, 40, 200, 1000, 5000, 25000, 125000, 625000, 3125000}

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Do you know what is wrong with my code? Why I can't get the numerical value?

Answer (score 3):

You can introduce a memory variable b[n] and solve for both a[n] and b[n].

```
RecurrenceTable[{a[n + 1] == 4 b[n], b[n] == b[n - 1] + a[n], 
   a[1] == b[1] == 2}, {a, b}, {n, 1, 10}][[All, 1]]

(*   {2, 8, 40, 200, 1000, 5000, 25000, 125000, 625000, 3125000}   *)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

In your code, you have the wrong syntax for the [`Sum`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sum.html). However, even with the correct syntax

```
rt = RecurrenceTable[{a[n + 1] == 4 Sum[a[i], {i, 1, n}], a[1] == 2}, 
  a, {n, 1, 10}]
```

[image]

As stated in the error message, all instances of `a[_]` must have arguments of the form `n + integer`

Amplifying on the answer by Suba Thomas

```
a[1] = 2;
a[n_] := a[n] = 4 Sum[a[i], {i, n - 1}]

seq = Table[a[n], {n, 1, 10}]

(* {2, 8, 40, 200, 1000, 5000, 25000, 125000, 625000, 3125000} *)
```

You can use [`FindSequenceFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindSequenceFunction.html) to generalize from the sequence

```
y[n_] = FindSequenceFunction[seq, n]
```

[image]

```
a[200] == y[200]

(* True *)
```

Comment: This FindSequenceFunction is pretty neat! Thanks for showing.